# How to Read Data From Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently trying to read the data from the firestore firebase, however it did not display any error in the console and or displaying any data on the screen. Anyone know which part is going wrong and please help me to solve the problem or point out the mistake? Appreciate those help, thank you.

**Code:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
class CarDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<CarDetails> createState() => _CarDetailsState();
}

class _CarDetailsState extends State<CarDetails> {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            "Car Details",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        drawer: const DrawerListBar(),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db
                .collection(currentUser.uid)
                .doc()
                .collection("vehicle details")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var carDetails = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 24, right: 24, top: 50),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 25, bottom: 15, right: 20, top: 10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  color: const Color(0xFF203e5a),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      carDetails["number plate"],
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const Text(
                                      "price/hr",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        CarItems(
                                            name: "Brand",
                                            value: carDetails["brand"]),
                                        CarItems(
                                            name: "Model",
                                            value: carDetails["model"]),
                                        CarItems(
                                            name: "Year",
                                            value: carDetails["year"]),
                                        CarItems(
                                            name: "Mileage",
                                            value: carDetails["mileage"]),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                right: 30,
                                child: Image.asset("Images/rolls_royce.png"),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return const Text("No data");
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Image of Firebase Collection**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `builder` fails to handle error. The first few lines should always be something like this:

```
...
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}"); // 
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ...
```

While this will not immediately fix the problem, it might surface the root cause.

---

The second problem is here:

```
stream: db
        .collection(currentUser.uid)
        .doc()
        .collection("vehicle details")
```

The `doc()` here generates a unique ID for a (at this point) non-existing document, so there won't be a `vehicle details` subcollection under it either.

If you know which document the `vehicle details` is under, you should pass that value to `doc(<ID here>)`.

If you doin't know which document the `vehicle details` is under, all you can do is read across all `vehicle details` collections by [using a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: Hello sir, I have added it already but it still didn't show any error, so what is the problem that causing data can't be display?